# Wolfe vs Wolfe-Powell stopping conditions

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I've been researching line search algorithms recently and there's one detail that is not entirely clear to me.
Is there any (practical) difference between Wolfe and Wolfe-Powell stopping conditions?
The mathematical formulation and the constants differ slightly. 
The **strong Wolfe** conditions as described in Nocedal & Wright are basically:
*Sufficient decrease (Armijio rule):*
$f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k}+\alpha _{k}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k})\leq f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k})+c_{1}\alpha _{k}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}^{{{\mathrm  T}}}\nabla f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k})$ with $c_{1}=10^{{-4}}$ 
*Curvature*
${{\big |}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}^{{{\mathrm  T}}}\nabla f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k}+\alpha _{k}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}){\big |}\leq c_{2}{\big |}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}^{{{\mathrm  T}}}\nabla f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k}){\big |}}$ with $c_{2}=0.1$ for non linear CG methods

Now in other texts as [this one](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~kandler/Hanoi2013/Lecture_NLO/bms-basic-NLP_120609.pdf) (§2.3) the **strong Wolfe-Powell** conditions are defined as:
*Sufficient decrease (Armijio rule):*
{$f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k}+\alpha _{k}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k})\leq f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k})+\sigma\alpha _{k}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}^{{{\mathrm  T}}}\nabla f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k})$ with $\sigma\in(0,0.5)$ 
*Curvature*
${{\big |}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}^{{{\mathrm  T}}}\nabla f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k}+\alpha _{k}{\mathbf  {p}}_{k}){\big |}\leq -\rho {\mathbf  {p}}_{k}^{{{\mathrm  T}}}\nabla f({\mathbf  {x}}_{k})}$ with $\rho\in [\sigma, 1) $

I've read that the Wolfe-Powell condition should be preferable for conjugate gradients methods that compute the direction ${\mathbf  {p}}_{k}$ with the Polak-Ribiere formula. 
Is this the actual case? I couldn't find anything on this specific topic. Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the first just a specific case of the second?

Comment: They seem to be equivalent, because for a descent direction $\mathbf{p}_k,$  the product $\mathbf{p}_k^T \Delta f(\mathbf{x}_k)$ would always be negative. IIRC what makes the second set ``strong'' is the requirement $\rho > \sigma.$